# Unique set of relationships to a table in a many to many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say we have `Parent1`, `Parent2`, `Child1` and `Child2`.

If `Parent1` is related to both `Child1` and `Child2`, then how to forbid `Parent2` relating to both `Child1` and `Child2` also.

---

Example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE parent (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE child (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE parent_child (
  parent_id INTEGER REFERENCES parent,
  child_id INTEGER REFERENCES child
);

INSERT INTO parent VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO parent VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO child VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO child VALUES (2);

INSERT INTO parent_child (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO parent_child (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO parent_child (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (2, 1);

-- Should not allow the following insert:
INSERT INTO parent_child (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (2, 2);
```

parent1 already has children `[1,2]`.
After inserting, parent2 would have children `[1,2]` also. Which should not be allowed because `[1,2] == [1,2]`.

However, if I added a 3rd child:
parent1 has children `[1,2]`
parent2 has children `[1,2,3]`
That would be fine because `[1,2] != [1,2,3]`

---

For some context: I'm modeling [Apriori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) and don't want duplicate "itemsets".

Comment: Please explain more

Comment: When can a child have many parents and how many, when can a parent be "shared" between children etc? You need to explain the rules/logic much better.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson There's no restriction on the number of parents a child can have. As long as no two parents have the same set of children.

Comment: Are you looking to insert parent_id, child_id in the table parent_child if the same combination is not already exists?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to insert parent_id, child_id in the table parent_child if the same combination is not already exists, then you can try IF NOT EXISTS in SQL as below-

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM parent_child
    WHERE parent_id = 2
    AND child_id = 2
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO parent_child (parent_id, child_id) 
    VALUES (2, 2);
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger.

Add row numbers for the children under each parent, sorted by child_id.

Then you can compare the current parent to the rest and find a parnet with exactly the same children.

If such a match is found - block the INSERT operation.

```
if EXISTS(
    SELECT  parent_id
    FROM (
            (       SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY parent_id ORDER BY child_id ) 
            AS RowNum, 
            child_id 
            FROM parent_child WHERE parent_id =2
            ) AS a 
            INNER JOIN
            (       SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY parent_id ORDER BY child_id ) 
            AS RowNum, 
            child_id,
            parent_id
            FROM parent_child WHERE parent_id <>2
            ) AS b 
            ON a.child_id = b.child_id AND a.RowNum = b.RowNum
        )
            ) then ---...block the INSERT
```